# How to change a node value in XML if another node is empty

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the response below from an WS

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="XX" xmlns:ns2="XX">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns2:entregarManifestacaoProcessualResposta>
            <ns1:sucesso>true</ns1:sucesso>
            <ns1:mensagem>Some strange error messafe</ns1:mensagem>
            <ns1:protocoloRecebimento>XXXXXXXX</ns1:protocoloRecebimento>
            <ns1:dataOperacao>XXXXXXX</ns1:dataOperacao>
            <ns1:recibo/>
        </ns2:entregarManifestacaoProcessualResposta>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

They haven't implemented according to the contract expressed, and in this situation the success must be false because the tag `<ns1:recibo>` is empty.

So I need to make an XSLT to check is `recibo` is empty and change the `sucesso` node to false.

I've started with the example below, that I've found here in SO, but when I try to change the `sucesso` node it never changes.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Envelope/Body/sucesso">
    <sucesso>false</sucesso>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to make an XSLT to check is `recibo` is empty and change the
>   `sucesso` node to false.

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns2="XX">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns2:sucesso[not(../ns2:recibo/text())]">
    <xsl:copy>false</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```